# position text at the top of cell in table if there is a large text in the second cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to position the text at the top of the box as it is declared, but when the column on the right contains a long text, it automatically changes to the bottom of the box

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%% Je suis francophone !
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
%% Je veux utiliser néanmoins des fontes qui « paraissent bien » en PDF
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{||C{0.5cm}||C{5cm}||C{4cm}||C{6.5cm}||} 

\hline 
\cellcolor{Gray} \textbf{RG} & \textbf{Définition} & \textbf{Mapping} & \textbf{Règles de gestion spécifiques}\\  
\hline
\hline  
\multicolumn{1}{||L{0.5cm}|}{\parbox{0.5cm}{1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|L{5cm}|}{\footnotesize {Portail \-Date Traitement Courant}} & \multicolumn{1}{|L{4cm}|}{\scriptsize{RBP \_ vTBADMRBP \_ SUIVI \_ APPLI.D \_ TRAIT}} & \multicolumn{1}{|L{6.5cm}||}{\footnotesize {CASE
WHEN [RBP \- Presentation View].[Dimension \- Référentiel Datamart].[L\_DATMR] = 'PORTAIL' THEN [RBP \- Presentation View].[Fait \- Suivi Application].[D\_TRAIT]
END}} \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Équipe de travail}
\end{table}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! you declare that you like to have text at bottom of cells. change `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}` to `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }p{#1}}` etc. beside this your document has many other issues: float cannot be inside `center` environment, etc.

Comment: You've already asked he same question in your previous post: [position-text-at-the-top-of-cell-in-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433381/position-text-at-the-top-of-cell-in-table) and a solution was proposed in the comments. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes i try it but it woudn't work

Comment: What did you try exactly? Changing `b` to `p` in the definition of the `L` column type does do what you ask.

Answer (score 3):

- your question is duplicate to your question [position-text-at-the-top-of-cell-in-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433381/position-text-at-the-top-of-cell-in-table)
- your question is answered in the comments under your the first and this questions
- beside this problem your document has other issues as:

  - float had not be inside other environments, ie. your

    ```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    ...
    \end{table}
    \end{center}
    ```

    is wrong
  - table width is larger than text width, consequently it spill out of a page
  - what means `\-`?
  - to my taste table is ugly :-( (about table design is worth a look [Wie Tabellen eigentlich aussehen sollten:](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/)

see, if the following redesign of your table is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,    % option for color napes
               french,      % option for babel (Je suis francophone!)
               12pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}         % instead of the "[cyr]{aeguill}"

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % new
\usepackage{booktabs,       % new
            makecell,       % new
            tabularx}       % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % redefined

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
    >{\large}c
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L
    >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}L   @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{RG}
    &   \thead[l]{Définition}
        &   \thead[l]{Mapping}
            &   \thead[l]{Règles de gestion spécifiques}                                               \\
    \midrule
1   & Portail Date Traitement Courant
        & RBP vTBADMRB \_SUIVI\_APPLI.D \_TRAIT
            &   CASE WHEN

                [RBP Presentation View].[Dimension Référentiel Datamart].[L\_DATMR]

                = 'PORTAIL' THEN [RBP  Presentation View].[Fait Suivi Application].[D\_TRAIT] END  \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Équipe de travail}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**edit:**
i consider comment of [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) and accordingly corrected text in table.

Comment: `\-` is used to manually indicate a hyphenation point (e.g. `hyphe\-nation`), but used between words as here it's quite unnecessary.

Comment: i know this, but not on the way how op used, for example `Fait \- Suivi`. this hasn't any sense (is superfluous). i suspect that op try to write `Fait\_Suivi`, (what also has sense :-) ). i will correct my answer asap.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Might just be due to a misunderstanding of what `\-` does.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thank you very much for editing my answer and for comment about `\-`. in the first my comment i try to write "(what also hasn't much sense :-) )" .  i corrected  text in table accordingly.