# Vertical line in table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to put  a vertical line to the table
 [image]

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}         % instead of the "[cyr]{aeguill}"

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % new
\usepackage{booktabs,       % new
            makecell,       % new
            tabularx}       % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % redefined


%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
    >{\large}c
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L
    >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}L   @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{RG}
    &   \thead[l]{Définition}
        &   \thead[l]{Mapping}
            &   \thead[l]{Règles de gestion spécifiques}                                               \\
    \midrule
1   & Portail Date Traitement Courant
        & RBP vTBADMRB \_SUIVI\_APPLI.D \_TRAIT
            &   CASE WHEN

                [RBP Presentation View].[Dimension Référentiel Datamart].[L\_DATMR]

                = 'PORTAIL' THEN [RBP  Presentation View].[Fait Suivi Application].[D\_TRAIT] END  \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Équipe de travail}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I wouldn,'t recommend it, espacially with `booktabs`  rules– vertical rules will be broken. But anyway, *where* in your table do you want to have vertical rules?

Comment: Where do you want that vertical line? Most people on this site (me included) will probably tell you that the output with `booktabs` without vertical rules as it is now is just fine.

Comment: I want juste make this table like a normal table with vertical and horizontal ligne :)

Comment: to make ugly table from this nice one you should: (i) replace `\toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule` with `\hline` (ii) table specifier change to: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\large}c|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L||
    >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}L|}`

Comment: bte, you use code from the answer on your question:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433428/position-text-at-the-top-of-cell-in-table-if-there-is-a-large-text-in-the-second. doing this it would be nice, that you accept this answer (by clicking on the check mark on the top left side of answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Zarko's two-rule uglification principle:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}         % instead of the "[cyr]{aeguill}"

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % new
\usepackage{booktabs,       % new
            makecell,       % new
            tabularx}       % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % redefined    

%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|
    >{\large}c|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}L|   @{}}
    \hline
\thead[l]{RG}
    &   \thead[l]{Définition}
        &   \thead[l]{Mapping}
            &   \thead[l]{Règles de gestion spécifiques}                                               \\
    \hline
1   & Portail Date Traitement Courant
        & RBP vTBADMRB \_SUIVI\_APPLI.D \_TRAIT
            &   CASE WHEN

                [RBP Presentation View].[Dimension Référentiel Datamart].[L\_DATMR]

                = `PORTAIL' THEN [RBP  Presentation View].[Fait Suivi Application].[D\_TRAIT] END  \\

    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Équipe de travail}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @YacineChamane, of course it works! since answer fulfill your request, you should consider to accept it. as i mentioned in my comment below your question (so far you not accept any of received answers).