# Center text in first row

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

How can i make the text in the first row in the center of cell, and how i can make number "1" in the center of cell as it is indicated with a red rectangle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}         % instead of the "[cyr]{aeguill}"

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % new
\usepackage{booktabs,       % new
            makecell,       % new
            tabularx}       % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % redefined    

%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|
    >{\large}c|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}L|   @{}}
    \hline
\thead[l]{RG}
    &   \thead[l]{Définition}
        &   \thead[l]{Mapping}
            &   \thead[l]{Règles de gestion spécifiques}                                               \\
    \hline
1   & Portail Date Traitement Courant
        & RBP vTBADMRB \_SUIVI\_APPLI.D \_TRAIT
            &   CASE WHEN

                [RBP Presentation View].[Dimension Référentiel Datamart].[L\_DATMR]

                = `PORTAIL' THEN [RBP  Presentation View].[Fait Suivi Application].[D\_TRAIT] END  \\

    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Équipe de travail}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is time to read packages documentations, isn't it? instead `\thead[l]{...}` you should write `\thead{...}`. number one is in the place where you require in one of your previous question. put it in `\multirow` cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fot the column head, remove the `[t]` option of `thead` to have the defalt alignment (centred both vertically and horizontally). For the  position of `1`, you can use `\multirowcell`   wwith a small adjustment. Since you load `makecell, I use it to add some vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells,  with`\setcellgapes`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm} % instead of the "[cyr]{aeguill}"

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % new
\usepackage{booktabs, % new
            multirow,
            makecell, % new
            tabularx} % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % redefined

%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|
    >{\large}c|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}L|
    >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}L| @{}}
    \hline
\thead{RG}
    & \thead{Définition}
        & \thead{Mapping}
            & \thead{Règles de gestion spécifiques} \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{1}[-4ex] {1}& Portail Date Traitement Courant
        & RBP vTBADMRB \_SUIVI\_APPLI.D \_TRAIT
            & CASE WHEN

                [RBP Presentation View].[Dimension Référentiel Datamart].[L\_DATMR]

                = `PORTAIL' THEN [RBP Presentation View].[Fait Suivi Application].[D\_TRAIT] END \\

    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Équipe de travail}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as i said in my comment ... op has `\thead[l]{...}` not `\thead[t]{...}` . and congratulation, your answer to him is the first one which he accepted :-).

Comment: Thanks, @Zarko. B.t.w., I'm surprised the code for the relative widths of the `X` columns seems to work nicely: the documentation says the sum of the coefficients should be equal to the number of X columns – in other words they should be 0.75 and 1.5 instead of 0.25 and 0.5. I wonder whether the way of coding `X` columns changed recently in this respect?

Comment: as far as i know, the package `tabu` is not maintained for years, so nothing is changed. code, which op use, is from my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433428/position-text-at-the-top-of-cell-in-table-if-there-is-a-large-text-in-the-second/433433#433433, where i consider that sum is equal 1 (`0.25`,  `0.25` and `0.5`). however, the same result is obtained with `1`, `1` and `2`, which sum is integer 4. or as you say `0.75`, `0,75` and `1,5`. in all cases the ration between `X` columns width is the same. as i remember `tabu` in this follows to `tabularx`