# Vertical Alignment in Table doesnt work

Tags: tables, tabu, vertical

I'm trying to understand the vertical aligment in a table, because i have to use it in a project. I tried multiple answers in different question but none seem to work for me (eg. [here](https://texblog.org/2019/06/03/control-the-width-of-table-columns-tabular-in-latex/), [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Tables_with_fixed_length) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71315/vertical-alignment-in-tabular)).

Latex seems to ignore all but the last aligment. Is it possible to align each column or just the whole table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{|p{5em}|m{5em}|b{5em}|b{2em}|}
    \hline
    test & test & test & s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5em}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}b{5em}|p{2em}|}
    \hline
    test & test & test & s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of the two tables]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your `tabular` code  makes it look like you're trying to influence both the horizontal (`\raggedright`, `\centering`, and `\raggedleft`) *and* the vertical placement (the `p`,`m`, and `b` column types) of the cells' contents. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to influence the vertical placement in each column separate.
With the second table i wanted to show that the horizontal aligment works for each column.

Comment: Unrelated but don't use the tabu package, it is broken and unmaintained. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment doesn't describe the alignment between the columns but the alignment of a column in relation to the overall baseline of the row.

Columns with only one line are always on the baseline. If they have more then one line they are adjusted.

I removed the tabu package as it is currently broken and unmaintained and shouldn't be used with a current LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{l|p{5ex}|m{5ex}|b{5ex}|p{2em}||m{2em}|b{2em}|}
    \hline
    \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(20,0);baseline
     & test 
     & test 
     & test 
     & s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s 
     & s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s
     & s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation :)