Carrying over a table sub-header using Longtables
First time user of LaTex, and first time poster. I hope the formatting comes out well.
I am developing a document table template using MikTex within TexStudio. I have spent quite a bit of time experimenting with different packages; i.e., NiceMatrix, Tabularx, Longtables, and Booktabs to gain a better understanding on their functions, as well as trying to nail down a look and feel for my tables.
My restrictions for this template are:

The table cannot be in landscape view
The table caption must carry over to subsequent pages
The column width must be fixed for each column header. I cannot have a different size table from document to document based on text width; e.g., CONDITIONS descriptions can vary in length.
Footnotes should only be listed at the last page of the table.

I am so very close, so I would like some insight which leads to the pertinent questions for this post:

I would like the 'sub header' (see FOURTH CHARACTERISTICS) on page 1 to also carry over long with the main header to the next page. If the table extends to a third page this means the sub-header would also be a different name yet again. The problem is that this sub-header can vary from document to document. Is this possible to achieve with LongTables?
How to list footnotes after the entire table on the last page.

Any advice would be appreciated. My minimum working example is below.
.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}      
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% multirow needed to allow for merging of cells
\usepackage{multirow}
% array needed to center vertically in a cell
\usepackage{array}
% custom caption, removes the whitespace between the table caption and the table
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=1em}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \normalsize % change this to \small if you can't fit the table in the page width
    \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}cccccm{5.75cm}}
        
        % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628544/vertical-alignment-in-longtable-cells
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In felis mi, vehicula vitae vestibulum volutpat, porta eu dui. Proin at elementum metus. Fusce mollis, lacus quis sagittis vulputate, libero ipsum tempus urna, nec iaculis erat lorem quis purus. Aliquam tristique lacus in erat laoreet convallis. Pellentesque ut accumsan risus. In ac mi euismod tortor dictum scelerisque. Aliquam consectetur ex id tellus dignissim iaculis. Curabitur et turpis lectus.} 
        \label{tab:long} \\
        
        \toprule
        \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
        \textbf{PARAMETER} & \textbf{SYMBOL} & \textbf{MIN} & \textbf{TYP} & \textbf{MAX} & \textbf{UNIT} & \textbf{CONDITIONS} \\ 
        \cmidrule{1-7}
        \endhead
        
        \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{First Characteristics}\\ 
        \midrule
        
        Parameter of 0  & Limit     & 2.7       &           & 45\footnotemark[1]\footnotetext[1]{Here be a footnote}        & v         & some text description \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Parameter of 1}     & \multirow{2}{*}{merge me}     & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & \centering v          & This is description of condition for 1        \\
            &   & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         & This is description of condition for 2    \\
        Parameter of 3  & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 4  & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 5  & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\
        
        \toprule
        \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{Second Characteristics}\\ 
        \midrule
        
        Parameter of 6 longer           & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &   \\
        Parameter of 7 much longer      & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &   \\
        Parameter of 8 watch the length & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &   \\
        Parameter of 9      & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &   \\
        Parameter of A      & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v     &   \\
        Parameter of B      & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &   \\
        
        Parameter of C      & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &   I may be a long description \\
        Parameter of D      & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &   I could well be a longer description\\
        Parameter of E      & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &   \\
        Parameter of F      & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &   \\
        Parameter of 10     & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v     &   \\
        Parameter of 11     & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &   \\
        
        \toprule
        \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{Third Characteristics}\\ 
        \midrule
        
        Parameter of 12     & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 13     & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 14     & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 15     & Limit         & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 16     & Limit         & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 17     & Limit         & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\
        
        Parameter of 18     & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 19     & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 1A     & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 1B     & Limit         & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 1C     & Limit         & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 1D     & Limit         & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\
        
        \toprule
        \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Fourth Characteristics}}\\ 
        \midrule
        
        Parameter of 1E     & Limit     & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 1F     & Limit     & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 20     & Limit     & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 21     & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 22     & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
        Parameter of 23     & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\
        
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}



welcome! what do you mean by different documents? you of course can change things in another document, so it isn't obvious what you mean. IFourth characteristics isn't a sub-header. It's marked up as a cell spanning the width of the table, so it obviously won't get repeated. the most straightforward way to do this with longtable, I think, would be to code them as separate tables and specify the column widths explicitly. that way you can keep them the same with some minor inconvenience. at least longtable offers no support for a sub-header mid-table as far as I'm aware.

off-topic: you can't load the same package twice with different options. you should be getting a warning on the console/in the log when you do this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community what do you want? blood? yes, the 'different documents' is unclear, but this is otherwise a solid first question.

Do you mean that all columns except last should have equal width? Do you aware that in this case contents in the first column can be broken into more text lines? Is this acceptable to you=? Your demands can be relatively easy solved by use xltabular or longtblr of tabularray package.

Apologies for the confusion everyone.
@cfr - I am creating a document template, so I would like the last cell spanning the width of the table to be repeated with the Header; e.g., Fourth Characteristics in this specific example. From your explanation, it sounds like this is not possible. It was worth a shot.
The reasoning is that the last cell spanning the width of the table is what I use as a sub-header and carrying it over to the next page can add clarity to the reader.
Thank you for your advice.

@Zarko you're the expert, but I don't see how the first would help and I can't find documentation for the second. the third maybe, but I'm not sure it would count as 'easy' :-)?

@cfr, after writing my comment I rethinking about OP demands. It is easy to define equal with of columns and make footnotes at the end of table (as you suggest in your answer +1), but how to solve rest of demands is unclear and not so easy. Even worse, to my opinion, it leads to new problems about which OP is not aware yet. SO I give-up to prepare my answer.

@Zarko hmm, yes. I think the sub-headings thing is not easy at all ;). they are not really subheadings and I don't see any easy way to make them so. as I understand the question, I don't think equal widths are wanted. I think they just mustn't change within the table. (since they can't change within the table, this is easily satisfied, at least.) my only idea for the subheadings would be different tables with explicit widths. that would work, but would be quite faffy.

@cfr (and Zarko) Going back to my question about "equal column width", I should clarify. Since this is a template that I will use for all my documents the column widths will not change once I nail down this template. I adjusted each column width to make sure the table is centered within my 0.5in right/left margins. I have read a lot of LaTex questions asking why their longtable is not centered or extends to far to the right, so I am happy with my solution unless there are clever-er tricks.
There really are only two questions, and I think everyone has answered them.

@NetRunner If you want to guarantee the column widths are the same in different documents, don't use c. In that case, you need to stick to e.g. p or m or similar and specify the width explicitly because c adjusts to the width of the cells. But I'm not sure whether that's really a problem or whether you just want the general look and first and last columns to be uniform.

you can to some extend exchange the header in the middle of a longtable, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263597/2388 for two options.

I don't know whether to post this or not as it answers only one of your questions1.
This demonstrates how to turn the footnotes into table notes using threeparttablex. For non-long tables, I have code which numbers the notes automatically, but that seems to break if table notes are used for longtable. threeparttablex does, however, render the markers referable and makes it possible to use them with longtable relatively conveniently.
This also automates production of the 'sub-headings', but I am not sure it is possible to include these into the table header with longtable2.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[small,bf,tableposition=below]{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=1em}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \ltsubcap { m }
{%
  \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{#1}\\
  \midrule
}

\begin{document}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
    \item[1] \label{tn:aside} Here be a footnote
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}cccccm{5.75cm}}

    % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628544/vertical-alignment-in-longtable-cells
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In felis mi, vehicula vitae vestibulum volutpat, porta eu dui. Proin at elementum metus. Fusce mollis, lacus quis sagittis vulputate, libero ipsum tempus urna, nec iaculis erat lorem quis purus. Aliquam tristique lacus in erat laoreet convallis. Pellentesque ut accumsan risus. In ac mi euismod tortor dictum scelerisque. Aliquam consectetur ex id tellus dignissim iaculis. Curabitur et turpis lectus.}
    \\

    \toprule
    \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}
    \textbf{PARAMETER} & \textbf{SYMBOL} & \textbf{MIN} & \textbf{TYP} & \textbf{MAX} & \textbf{UNIT} & \textbf{CONDITIONS} \\
    \cmidrule{1-7}
    % \ltsubcaption
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes\\
    \endlastfoot

    \ltsubcap{First Characteristics}
    % avoid multiply defined labels
    \label{tab:long}
    Parameter of 0  & Limit     & 2.7       &           & 45\tnotex{tn:aside}  & v         & some text description \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{Parameter of 1}     & \multirow{2}{*}{merge me}     & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & \centering v          & This is description of condition for 1        \\
                                        &   & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         & This is description of condition for 2    \\
    Parameter of 3  & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 4  & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 5  & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\

    \toprule
    \ltsubcap{Second Characteristics}

    Parameter of 6 longer           & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &   \\
    Parameter of 7 much longer      & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &   \\
    Parameter of 8 watch the length & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &   \\
    Parameter of 9      & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &   \\
    Parameter of A      & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v     &   \\
    Parameter of B      & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &   \\

    Parameter of C      & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &   I may be a long description \\
    Parameter of D      & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &   I could well be a longer description\\
    Parameter of E      & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &   \\
    Parameter of F      & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &   \\
    Parameter of 10     & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v     &   \\
    Parameter of 11     & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &   \\

    \toprule
    \ltsubcap{Third Characteristics}

    Parameter of 12     & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 13     & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 14     & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 15     & Limit         & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 16     & Limit         & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 17     & Limit         & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\

    Parameter of 18     & Limit         & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 19     & Limit         & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 1A     & Limit         & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 1B     & Limit         & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 1C     & Limit         & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 1D     & Limit         & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\

    \toprule
    \ltsubcap{Fourth Characteristics}

    Parameter of 1E     & Limit     & 2.7       &           & 45        & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 1F     & Limit     & 1.8       & 2.2       & 2.4       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 20     & Limit     & 100.25    & 99.5      & 100       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 21     & Limit     & 1000      & 1.0       & 2.2       & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 22     & Limit     & 4.8       & 0.50      & 0.75      & v         &       \\
    Parameter of 23     & Limit     & 0.125     & 0.100     & 0.250     & v         &       \\

  \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}

1This is a hazard when asking several questions together rather than abiding by the SE one-question-per-question rule, but when they are very closely connected separate questions can produce only incompatible answers ...
2Translation: I have no idea.
